# pandas to loop through DataFrames and keep only specified column headings. Error results if specified heading is not in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, heading

I want to use pandas in python to loop through multiple DataFrames and keep only headings from a specified keep_col list. The code results in an error if a DataFrame does not contain a specified heading (KeyError: "['str2'] not in index").

The following pandas code creates 2 example DataFrames with differing column heading names:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,5), columns=('A','B','str1','str2','str3'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,3), columns=('A','B','str1'))
print df1
print df2
```

output DataFrames

```
 A         B         str1      str2      str3
-0.152686  0.189076 -1.079168 -0.823674  1.489668
-1.272144  0.694862  0.036248  0.319550  0.782666

 A         B         str1
 0.310152  1.302962 -0.284632
 1.046044  0.090650  0.861716
```

The code below results in an error because 'str2' is not in 'df2'.

How can this be modified to ignore a 'keep_col' list string if it is not in a DataFrame heading?

```
#delete columns
keep_col = ['A','str2'] #need code here to ignore 'str2' when generating 'df2'
new_df1 = df1[keep_col] 
new_df2 = df2[keep_col]

print new_df1
print new_df2
```

This is the desired output:

```
 A          str2    
-0.152686  -0.823674
-1.272144   0.319550

 A       
 0.310152  
 1.046044
```

This example is for simplicity. I will be looping through 100+ .csv files to keep only specified columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [filter()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) function in conjunction with RegEx:

```
In [79]: mask = r'^(?:A|str2)$'

In [80]: df1.filter(regex=mask)
Out[80]:
          A      str2
0 -1.190226 -0.123637
1 -1.782685  0.219820

In [81]: df2.filter(regex=mask)
Out[81]:
          A
0  0.207736
1 -0.013273
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! Although this solved my posted example, I need the regex to match exactly rather than 'if contains' string. I tried  r'(?:)\b(A|str2)\b' but this did not work for my actual application as i have multiple headings that are very similar but differ by only a character or punctuation.

Comment: @JordanChristian, i've updated my answer - please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to generate a list of all column headers that are in `keep_col`.

```
new_df1 = df1[[c for c in df1.columns if c in keep_col]]
new_df2 = df1[[c for c in df2.columns if c in keep_col]]

print new_df1
>>>
          A      str2
0  1.480978  0.369485
1 -0.969107  0.767707

print new_df2
>>>
          A
0  1.480978
1 -0.969107
```